# How do I include an if statement in a mustache file?

Tags: html, if-statement, mustache

My app allows users to create and edit goals. In the 'createGoal' mustache file, a select box allows the user to choose 1 of 3 goal categories:

```
`<label for="category">Category</label>
<select id="category" name="category">
    <option value="Option1">Option1</option>
    <option name="category" value="Option2">Option2</option>
    <option name="category" value="Option3">Option3</option>
</select>`
```

When the user creates a new goal, the goal is given a category value that I would use in other mustache files like: {{category}}.
In the 'editGoal' mustache file, I can't work out how to make the category select box be pre-populated with the goal's {{category}} value.

I thought an if statement would work, for example:

```
`<label for="category">Category</label>
<select id="category" name="category">
    <option value="Option1" {{#if categoryIs "Option1"}}selected{{/if}}>Option1</option>
    <option value="Option2" {{#if categoryIs "Option2"}}selected{{/if}}>Option2</option>
    <option value="Option3" {{#if categoryIs "Option3"}}selected{{/if}}>Option3</option>
</select>`
```

But that doesn't work.

Comment: What does your input data look like?

Answer (score 0):

Mustache has a single tag type that can do loops, conditionals and helper functions, depending on what kind of data you feed it. It is called a *section tag*, which must have a matching *end section tag*, and it looks like this:

```
{{#key}}content{{/key}}
```

Here, `key` is any property in your data, just like when you would write `{{key}}`. If `key` dereferences to an array, the section content is repeated for each element of the array. If `key` dereferences to a function ("lambda" in Mustache jargon), that function is called and the return value used. In all remaining cases, the value that `key` dereferences to is coerced to boolean; if truthy, the section content is rendered, otherwise it is not rendered. You can read all the details in the [updated mustache(5) manpage](https://jgonggrijp.gitlab.io/wontache/mustache.5.html).

From the way your question is written, my impression is that your input data probably has a single `category` value, like this:

```json
{
    "category": "Option1"
}
```

In Mustache, it is conventional to preprocess the data before feeding it to the template. In your case, in order to stick as closely to the current form of your input data and template, you would have to add a boolean property of which the *name* depends on which category was chosen:

```json
{
    "category": "Option1",
    "choseOption1": true
}
```

With the data in this format, you can use section tags to add the `selected` attribute only to the `<option>` of the chosen goal category. Note that `choseOption2` and `choseOption3` need not be present in the data; their absence automatically counts as falsy.

```
<label for="category">Category</label>
<select id="category" name="category">
    <option value="Option1" {{#choseOption1}}selected{{/choseOption1}}>Option1</option>
    <option value="Option2" {{#choseOption2}}selected{{/choseOption2}}>Option2</option>
    <option value="Option3" {{#choseOption3}}selected{{/choseOption3}}>Option3</option>
</select>
```

You can past the following code in the load/store box of the [Wontache playground](https://jgonggrijp.gitlab.io/wontache/playground.html) to try the above combination of data and template:

```
{"data":{"text":"{\n    \"category\": \"Option1\",\n    \"choseOption1\": true\n}"},"templates":[{"name":"","text":"<label for=\"category\">Category</label>\n<select id=\"category\" name=\"category\">\n    <option value=\"Option1\" {{#choseOption1}}selected{{/choseOption1}}>Option1</option>\n    <option value=\"Option2\" {{#choseOption2}}selected{{/choseOption2}}>Option2</option>\n    <option value=\"Option3\" {{#choseOption3}}selected{{/choseOption3}}>Option3</option>\n</select>"}]}
```

That said, you can improve on the template by making more changes to the data. I suggest the following format:

```json
{
    "goals": [
        {"category": "Option1", "selected": "selected"},
        {"category": "Option2"},
        {"category": "Option3"}
    ]
}
```

With this, you can eliminate the repetition from your template. In the most straightforward case, you can use use section tags both for the repeated `<option>` element and for the conditional `selected` attribute:

```
<label for="category">Category</label>
<select id="category" name="category">
    {{#goals}}
    <option value="{{category}}" {{#selected}}selected{{/selected}}>{{category}}</option>
    {{/goals}}
</select>
```

Note that I wrote `"selected": "selected"` rather than `"selected": true`. I did that because it allows us to use a simple variable interpolation tag instead of a section for the `selected` attribute, as demonstrated below:

```
<label for="category">Category</label>
<select id="category" name="category">
    {{#goals}}
    <option value="{{category}}" {{selected}}>{{category}}</option>
    {{/goals}}
</select>
```

You can try both of the above templates by pasting the following code into the playground.

```
{"data":{"text":"{\n    goals: [\n        {category: 'Option1', selected: 'selected'},\n        {category: 'Option2'},\n        {category: 'Option3'},\n    ]\n}"},"templates":[{"name":"","text":"<label for=\"category\">Category</label>\n<select id=\"category\" name=\"category\">\n    {{#goals}}\n    <option value=\"{{category}}\" {{#selected}}selected{{/selected}}>{{category}}</option>\n    {{/goals}}\n</select>"},{"text":"<label for=\"category\">Category</label>\n<select id=\"category\" name=\"category\">\n    {{#goals}}\n    <option value=\"{{category}}\" {{selected}}>{{category}}</option>\n    {{/goals}}\n</select>"}]}
```